# How to call a controller method from an html page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In the application I am working on, I have an Html page inside views folder and I have mentioned the action as follows.

```
  <form name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" action="//Controllers/RegistrationController.cs">
```

The registration controller returns a view.

```
public ActionResult Detail(string name)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

When I run the program, I get server not found error.

I also tried changing the action string to `action="//Controllers/RegistrationController.cs/Detail"`
but got the same error.

Does the action string have to be written in some other way?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

You don't have to set the path like in your solution. You don't need to set `Controllers` because the framework knows that you mean the controller.

Assuming that you dont change the routing in `global.asax`, your `RegistrationController.cs` has an ActionMethod called `Detail` (decorated with `[HttpPost]`) and the following folder structure within your project.

- Controllers/RegistrationController.cs
- Views/Registration/Detail.cshtml

  ```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Registration", FormMethod.Post, new { @onSubmit =     "return validateForm();" }))
  {
      // Your Form's content
  }
  ```

Comment: Could you provide informations about your projects folder structure ?

Comment: The folder structure is exactly as you assumed.
Controllers/RegistrationController.cs
Views/Registration/Detail.cshtml

Comment: What was / is the problem ? Im a little confused that you accept my answer and wrote your comment. Glad to help you!

Comment: I made the changes according to the code that you had written here (before editing). But it didn't work because there were two forward slashes (//Register/Detail). I removed the first slash and got the desired result.
And, this new code works too.
Thank you very much

Comment: Ah ok, interesting. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the default routes (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`) you need:

```
action="/Registration/Detail"
```

Actually I would recommend you using HTML helpers to generate forms and never hardcode them as you did:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Registration", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form", onsubmit = "return validateForm();" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/registration/detail` - you don't need to reference the path to the actual file.  The framework finds the controller class and invokes the requested action for you.  It uses the routes as defined in `global.asax.cs` to determine the controller and action from the url.  The default route is `{controller}/{action}/{id}` where the first two have defaults of "Home" and "Index", respectively, and the third is optional.  You can change this if you want by adding/modifying the route set up.